# File's Size limit in MS SQl server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a DMS web application. I am able to upload the files in database. But the problem is when I upload a file with size say 5.61 MB along with some other files which are less than 50KB in size , and when I try to access the file through a grid view(selected index, using a link button), I get an error saying "The connection was reset while loading the page". I am attaching the screenshots.
Image 1) When heavy file is not loaded in DB.
Here I dont get any problem, the desired file gets opened in respective application(ms word,exel)

Image 2) When heavy file is loaded in DB.
Here when I click on 12 in the grid(this is a heavy file) I get Image three

Image 3) When I try to access this heavy file that I added

Now If i click any of the other files to see and fetch from DB. I get same page as image 3. For uploading the files with large MB size I have put the follwoing line in web.config in .

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true"/>
```

I am using an ajax file uploaded for uploading file.
Please let me know if any other Information is nedded.
Any suggestions...

**I am not able to upload images due to my number of reputoions.**

Comment: I dont understand one thing why are you uploading file in database you should upload file to server and save its path or filename in database am i wrong

Comment: @skhurams Not necessarily, in cases it might be 'better' to store BLOBs.

Comment: @skhurams : For efficient searching. If file is deleted on server its path remains, So I am stroing.

Comment: @GrantThomas : Can you suggest nethin? I am getting erroe as the connection was reset.